# Upload Image not working in firefox (Magento 1.9) frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images, image-upload, varien-file-uploader

I tried to upload some image product in frontend. Before, button browse and upload were missing, then I have upgraded the latest flash mozila (firefox) and then browse and upload button were there but when i choose some images and click button upload, the image cannot upload well, so why that is happen? can you tell me the solution ? this issue just only in mozila firefox, in chrome worked well.

Capture:

[image]

Comment: - use firebug to check javascript conflict?
- check the extension that you use for upload in frontend.

Comment: i still cannot solve it anyway. whats this issue cause of SSL ? 

"the connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains unecrypted elements (such as images) or the encryption is not strong enough" 

thats text said on the top beside of url firefox mozila. 

in front of web http://,
backend https://, 
in vendor page http://, 
but when going to product manager the url changed again to https://

Comment: I've resolved this same issue locally for my current employer by implementing my own HTML5 based file uploader and scrapping Magento's flash-based nightmare.  You may want to look into finding a modern replacement (or simply use a different browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any CDN, then it may cause problems like this. When i had faced a problem in uploading images to mobile module in Magento Community Version, i just disabled the CDN urls from settings->configuration->design and tried uploading the pictures, and it works.

So try disabling the CDN and upload. hope this fix

Comment: i'm not using CDN, so what should I do to solve this issue ?

Comment: So when i read the above comment of yours regarding the SSL conflict, can you disable the SSL on the website and try.

Comment: i've been trying, but what is this issue cause of SSL conflict? because only in firefox and operamini browser. in chrome worked well..

Comment: finally it solved. i just go to system > configuration > general > web > tab secure > set Use Secure URLs in Frontend and Use Secure URLs in Admin to 'NO'
you saved me!

Comment: Hi Stanly, if I have set it not secure, actually it works, but how to make it secure and passes certified from mozilla firefox and also can upload images ? let me know please..

Comment: I got one point, in some browser the versions of SSL will make some issue. Means when I used CloudFlare Global SSL , my site loads fine in SSL in Google Chrome, but it throws an security error on Mozilla.

Comment: I got one point, in some browser the versions of SSL will make some issue. Means when I used CloudFlare Global SSL , my site loads fine in SSL in Google Chrome, but it throws an security error on Mozilla.

Comment: so, what should i do ?